# What exactly does the phrase "pass a week" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Many years ago, on my way from Hongkong to New York, I **passed a week** in San Francisco.

What exactly does the phrase "pass a week" mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That perfectly natural American sentence is the beginning of [Ambrose Bierce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ambrose_Bierce)'s short story [Beyond the Wall](http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/BeyWal.shtml).  It means the narrator spent a week in San Francisco as a stopover while traveling from Hong Kong to New York.

For commentary on the “spending time” metaphor, see John Lawler's answers ([1](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/71849/11433), [2](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/72796/11433)) to the questions *[Single word for “time spent”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71838)* and *[The difference between “take” and “last”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/72789).*

Answer (score 1):

A more common way to say that is:

> [...]I **spent a week** in San Francisco.

It simply means that the speaker stayed in San Francisco for a week between visits to Hong Kong and New York.

I have only heard this kind of phrasing from French speakers. A literal translation from French will yield the "passed a week" phrasing.

Comment: It doesn't sound awkward to me, but the rest of this answer is exactly correct.

Comment: I can't recall this wording being used by a native English speaker before. Could be regional?

Comment: I found it in "Beyond the Wall" by Ambrose Bierce http://www.americanliterature.com/ss/featured/ssfeature.html

Comment: Edited; is this really used in common speech? I have never heard it in the midwest or west coast. In Brussels I only hear it from non-native English speakers. I wonder if it's a slightly theatrical tint which often borrows nuances from French.

Comment: Ambrose Bierce wrote at the end of the 19th century.  It's not suprising he would use now-outdated language.

Comment: Although saying things like, "I *passed the time* by playing solitaire." is still common.  So if you can *pass the time* then one could ask, "How much time?" which then leads to, "I passed a week."

Comment: @Jim that's a good point, but I don't know anybody (I think) that would respond "I passed a week" in that situation.

Comment: @Jim yes "Pass the time" is common, but the "leads to" logic does not really work in linguistics.

Comment: @tenfour: I wasn't talking about linguistics, I was talking about conversation.